# JMeter - Error in redirect URL for GET ....?

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and trying to get a small test running for proof of concept purposes - but am getting the following error recording the steps (basically log in, click around, log off)

Any suggestions ..?

```
2013/10/28 13:23:47 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET https://blabla.blagroup.com/Home/Default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Could not sanitize URL: /Pub/Login.aspx
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Pub/Login.aspx
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:226)

2013/10/28 13:23:49 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [54014] Empty request, ignored 
2013/10/28 13:23:49 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [54016] Empty request, ignored 
2013/10/28 13:23:49 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [54013] Empty request, ignored 
2013/10/28 13:23:49 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [54015] Empty request, ignored    etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug that has been fixed in nightly build:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55717

As a workaround, change in Https recorder http implementation to Java instead of HttpClient4 implementation.

If you want to give nightly build a try, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Read:

> Installing JMeter runtime
>
> Download the _bin and _lib files
>
> Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>
> The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Comment: Wow! I figured out that Java does the trick, but it looked kinda dirty. Good to know it's a bug ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error.  In "HTTP Request Defaults" I changed HTTP Request Implementation to "Java" as shown below.  That fixed it for me.

[image]